# Why am I getting Fail PDO connect

Tags: php, mysql

dbConnector.php

```
<?php

    class DbConnector {

    var $link;

    function DbConnector(){
            try{
                $this->link = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=system', 'root', '123456');
                $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die("this is not connected");
            }

        }

      //*** Function: query, Purpose: Execute a database query ***
      // this function fail to connect
    function query($query) {
        try{
        $this->link->prepare($query);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die("fail to prepare");
        }
        return $this->link->prepare($query);
    }

    }

    ?>
```

check.php

```
<?php
include("dbConnector.php");
$connector = new DbConnector();

$username ='';

$query = "SELECT air_users FROM USER_NAME WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
$result = $connector->query($query);
$result->execute(array($username));

$num = $result->rowCount();
$num = $result->fetch();

echo $num;
// mysql_close();
?>
```

I get return error

> fail to prepare

What did I do wrong? I double checked it but can't figure it out the error, I cannot get it connected to my database.

It just give me a error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a try/catch, which is great, but your issue is that you just echo that there is a problem, not what the problem is.

If you print out the error message from the exception, I'm sure you will get some more info on why it wont prepare:

```
try {
    $this->link->prepare($query);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Or just temporary remove the try/catch blocks and let the exception go off and show in the browser when testing.